# Order By Field IN Yii2

Tags: yii2

I got this problem and not found any solution with yii instrument. Someone know how to solve this problem ?

Eventually, i used this bad code

```
$params = [];
foreach ($recipeIds as $i => $recipeId) {
    $params[':id_'.$i] = $recipeId;
}

$recipes = Recipes::findBySql(
        'SELECT
            *
        FROM
            {{%recipes}}
        WHERE
            `id` IN ('.implode(', ',array_keys($params)).')
        ORDER BY
            FIELD (id, '.implode(',', array_reverse(array_keys($params))).')
        LIMIT
            :limit',
        $params + [':limit' => $this->count]
    )
    ->all();
```

How to solve with ::find() ?

UPD: should be like

```
$recipes = Recipes::find()
    ->where(['id' => $recipeIds])
    ->orderBy(['id' => array_reverse($recipeIds)])
    ->limit($this->count)
    ->all();
```

Comment: Which kind of problem do you have? Is $receipeId always numerical? At least you could tell us if you get an Yii or an sql error. Shall we guess?

Comment: I want made requert with yii criteria, like
 $recipes = Recipes::find()
->where(['id' => $recipeIds])
                    ->orderBy(['id' => array_reverse($recipeIds)])
                    ->limit($this->count)
                    ->all();

Comment: AFAIK, FIELD is not supported by orderBy(). But you could do it in php after getting the recipes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try that:

```
$recipes = Recipes::find()
    ->where(['in', 'id', $recipeIds])
    ->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD (id, ' . implode(',', array_reverse(array_keys($params))) . ')')])
    ->limit($this->count)
    ->all();
```

For use `orderBy` with `FIELD (...)` see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/553

Comment: thank you, very useful knowledge new \yii\db\Expression('..')

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question, today I have faced exactly the same issue, and below my solution for it so it can help anyone who faces the same issue.

Solution:

- Instead of using `$this->hasMany` use an `ActiveQuery`
- Use the property `$multiple` on the query to indicate that this query will return an array of results.
- Use `leftJoin` method, and define the junction table relation inside it.

Example:

```
public function getValues()
{
$query = Value::find()
->leftJoin(ItemHasValue::tableName(), ItemHasValue::tableName() . '. value_id = ' . Value::tableName() . '.id' )
->where([
// define all ur conditions here
])
$query->multiple = true;

return $query;
}
```

P.S refer to this link on the Yii Github issues tracker https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/17166