# Yii Framework; How to use OrderBy() with custom sorting

Tags: php, yii

I use Yii 2.x
I would like to use OrderBy() with custom sorting. But It go wrong.

How do I run something like this

```
MyTable::find()->orderBy('WHEN SORTING = '1' THEN '1' WHEN SORTING = '2' THEN '2' WHEN SORTING = '3' THEN '3' ELSE SORTING ASC')->all();
```

I also tried below but failed.

```
MyTable::find()->orderBy('FIELD(SORTING,1,2,3,0)')->all;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you asking about Yii 1.x ?

Comment: I use Yii 2.x. Thanks.

Comment: Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856562/order-by-field-in-yii2

Comment: Thanks for your link. But I tried MyTable::find()->orderBy(['SORTING' => array( 1, 2, 3, 0)]) 
It is failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using letteral sql code should work

```
MyTable::find()->orderBy(" FIELD(SORTING,1,2,3,0) ")->all();
```

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge, it is still error. the error message is as below. I give it up.  I choose to divide it into two query to handle.
 
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `myTable` ORDER BY FIELD (SORTING, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'0')`

Error Info: Array

Comment: Is the same error you get before or is different ..?

Comment: the error is different. if I type `MyTable::find()->orderBy('FIELD(SORTING,1,2,3,0)')->all`
the error message will be as below
_Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: yii\db\ActiveQuery::all_

Comment: I have slightly update the answer removing the single quotes .. anyway you must use all() whit the () ..

Comment: Yes I know that I need to add `()` to the method `all`. but it is still failed. I doubt that the yii don't support custom sorting for the method `orderBy`. In fact, I already tried more than 10 style of syntax. I tried one of the syntax that don't come with error message. but it is no effect at all. (I already forgot what the syntax is.)

Comment: Many Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your custom sorting using [\yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html) e.g

`->orderBy(new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD(SORTING,1,2,3,0)'))`