# Yii2 Array sorting

Tags: arrays, sorting, yii2

In my Yii2 Project I have an array for example

```
$array = [];    
$array [] = 8 , 3, 6
```

So when I print out the array is

```
[8,3,6]
```

So when I use the same in a where statement it jumbles up.

```
$class = ModelClass::find()->where(['array_no' => $array])->all
```

So when I print out class I get the output in asc order sorted..
I get the information of

- 3 in the first
- 6 in the second place
- 8 in the third place.

How can i stop this from happening. I want them to return my output in the same order as array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631723/maintaining-order-in-mysql-in-query this may be useful

Comment: In my yii2 syntax I cant use IN statment..

Comment: but can you use `orderBy` like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856562/order-by-field-in-yii2. Just create an expression with your array and pass it to order by statement.

Comment: Thank you -Andrey Mischenko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ORDER BY FIELD()`, e.g. :

```
$models = ModelClass::find()
  ->where(['array_no' => $array])
  ->orderBy(new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD (array_no, '.implode(',', $array).')'))
  ->all();
```

Comment: Yea but it throws me a undefine function call when I use yii/db/expression